# Finding "complete" groups in R

Tags: r

I have a large dataset of groups and subgroups. I want to filter the data according to the "completeness" of the groups, i.e. within each groups all levels of the sub-groups (a and b) should occur

A small example

```
group <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each=5)
a <- c(1,1,2,2,3,1,1,1,3,3,1,2,2,3,3)
b <- c("a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b")
df <- data.frame(group, a, b)

     group a b
1      A 1 a
2      A 1 a
3      A 2 a
4      A 2 b
5      A 3 c
6      B 1 a
7      B 1 a
8      B 1 a
9      B 3 b
10     B 3 c
11     C 1 a
12     C 2 b
13     C 2 b
14     C 3 b
15     C 3 b
```

So here only A would be considered complete because all levels of a and b occur. Is there an efficient (and flexible) way to filter with those conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(
    a_complete = all(unique(df$a) %in% a),
    b_complete = all(unique(df$b) %in% b)
  ) %>%
  filter(a_complete, b_complete) %>%
  select(- ends_with("complete"))
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this:

```
sapply(split(df, df$group), function(x) all(a %in% x$a) & all(b %in% x$b))
##    A     B     C 
##  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try `data.table`, something like

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, indx := length(unique(a)) + length(unique(b))]
df[, indx2 := length(unique(a)) + length(unique(b)), by = group]
df[indx == indx2]
#    group a b indx indx2
# 1:     A 1 a    6     6
# 2:     A 1 a    6     6
# 3:     A 2 a    6     6
# 4:     A 2 b    6     6
# 5:     A 3 c    6     6
```

Or for a more general solution, you can specify the column names and then use `.SDcols`, something like

```
cols <- c("a", "b")
setDT(df)[, indx := Reduce(sum, lapply(.SD, function(x) length(unique(x)))), .SDcols = cols]
df[, indx2 := Reduce(sum, lapply(.SD, function(x) length(unique(x)))), .SDcols = cols, by = group]
df[indx == indx2]
```